# Angular ngx-infinite-scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am developing Angular project and using **ngx-infinite-scroll** for displaying a page with data from a database. As I followed the user guide for **ngx-infinite-scroll**, i installed it via npm and then added the module to a file, that exports all modules in array:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AppRoutingModule} from '../../app-routing.module';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from "ngx-infinite-scroll";

export const ModulesExport= [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  InfiniteScrollModule
];
```

After that, I imported that array in my **app.module.ts** and added it to the importing modules.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

/* import all modules, services and components from package export files */
import {ProvidersExport} from './export/providers-services/export-providers';
import {ComponentsExport} from './export/components/export-components';
import {ExportComponentsObj} from './export/components/export-components-obj';
import {ModulesExport} from './export/modules/export-modules';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [...ComponentsExport],
  imports: [...ModulesExport],
  providers: [...ProvidersExport],
  bootstrap: [ExportComponentsObj.App]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So after everything is added and ready to go, I created my component and included the required parameters for infinite scroll in my html component:

```
<div class="row center container">
  <div class="journeysWrapper" style="height: 100%" infinite-scroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" (scroll)="loadMore()">
    <app-journey-preview *ngFor="let journey of journeys" [journey]="journey" [journeyCount]="journeys.length" class="center row container"></app-journey-preview>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am now trying to test if everything works correctly and just logging a sample string when the scrolling event is triggered:

```
  loadMore() {
    console.log('scrolled down!!');
  }
```

Unfortunately, when I load the page, I get the following error:

[image]

So now I am stuck with this error and I cannot figure out why does it appear. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What angular version are you using?

Comment: It looks like there was an issue with the plugin documentation. I checked the plugin github and noticed that they have forgotten to mention that a specific version is needed in order to run it on the new version of angular. After I made the changes, everything started to work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The function is Scrolled insted scroll,
(scrolled)="fn()"